# What makes a Literature Review paper good?

Tags: publications, ieee, literature-review, review-articles

I am currently doing my research thesis project for my Masters/PhD in area “X”. As expected, the first 2 months has been literature review, to actually know what I am doing.

The thing is, I haven’t found a paper that Reviews current research on area “X” ([this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01181) is the type of “review” paper that I am talking about). I have read about 100 papers in this past week on area “X” in these two months, and skimmed (i.e. only read interesting parts) through another 50.

Area “X” is a sub-field in Computational Electromagnetics. I have read papers from various Journals, mainly IEEE, but no review on the subtopic!

I have taken a lot of notes down of the different papers proposing different methods, different algorithms, different assumptions, etc. I have drawn schematics too identifying the sub-topics, the research directions, etc. And I think this could really help other research fellows! I don’t know, maybe I’m wrong.

I thought about doing a review on the current topic, and typing down a proper paper of about 15 pages. Would it be successful? If so, what is the usual advice for these type of submissions.

Comment: Have a look at IEEE Communications Tutorials and Surveys for many examples of high quality review articles.

Comment: Consider asking your advisor whether you should write a literature review paper.

Comment: What is your broad research discipline (that is, broader than the specific area of "Computational Electromagnetics")? Adding a related tag to your question might attract respondents who are familiar with what is expected in your domain. I assume from the IEEE tag that it is related to electrical and electronics engineering, but please be explicit.